# Delete the row with the highest id in mysql, using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete

I'm working on a really simple minichat program (`php/mysql`) which displays the last 10 messages.

I wanted to add a button to delete the last message (using a form, leading to a `php` file like the one under).

I'm really a beginner with `php` and `mysql` so, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Follows my code:

```
<?php 
    // Create connection
    $cn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

    // Check connection
    if($cn->connect_error)
    {
        echo "Connection failed : " . $cn->connect_error;
    }

    $sql = "DELETE FROM `minichat` WHERE `minichat`.`id` = ('SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `minichat`')";

    if($cn->query($sql) === TRUE){
            echo "Deleted succesfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $cn->error;
    }

    //header('Location: connexion.php');
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work ?

Comment: Show us the error, or explain what doesnt work

Comment: It doesn't delete the row, and it doesn't send any error with this code, but displays "Deleted successfully"

Comment: Check the error logs.

Comment: are DELETE privileges allowed? seeing an answer given didn't solve it, which it should have

Comment: *"I wanted to add a button to delete the last message (using a form, leading to a php file like the one under)."* - Well, if you are using one and didn't include it in the question and how it's used, how do we know if that isn't failing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the manual on [DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

> Subqueries
>
> You cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a
>   subquery.

So instead you should do something like:

```
DELETE FROM minichat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

And you probably want a condition to make sure a user can only delete his / her own comment..

Comment: ah, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Given also that DELETE privileges have been granted and that "said button" they're wanting to use, actually works ;-) as per my comments under the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll just assume it does ;-)

Comment: I'm curious as to why their query returned TRUE, when it should have returned FALSE, given they're checking for errors. Would MySQL fail silently if DELETE permissions were not granted? I'm trying to think outloud here of course. and/or it's just their unknown button failing? Error reporting perhaps not used? I'm baffled. Edit: Oh, so they said it does work. well *hip hip hourrah!*

Comment: Thank you ! The previous syntax was something I made up myself, without knowing these specifications. It works now, and I understand a lot more how it works !

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the single quote around the subselect

```
 "DELETE FROM `minichat` WHERE `minichat`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `minichat`)"
```

Otherwise you have WHERE `minichat`.`id` = 'mi string text'

and for fact that you can delete from a sub query you can  try

```
 DELETE 
FROM `minichat` 
WHERE `minichat`.`id` = (select t.id from (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `minichat`) t)
```

This is expected to exceed the limit for delete with subquery

Comment: Nice catch, didn't see that.

Comment: This doesn't work, it gievs the same result "Deleted successfully", but doesn't actually delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and set up a variable which collected the ID you want. Then you can refer to that variable as the ID you want to delete.

Comment: Isnt practical go to the db ask for the max id and then send a diferent query for delete.

Comment: Would I need to use a prepared query for that purpose ?

Comment: Yep so for example: $x = SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `minichat`)". For future reference if the query does not work open your sql editor and try to run it in there to see if it works